# Completar numero de registros da consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, firebird

Olá! tenho uma tabela no BD que pode conter de 0 há 12 registros.
(como uma tabela de renda mensal durante o ano. totalizando 12 registros)

quero fazer uma consulta nessa tabela e quero que ela me retorne exatos 12 registros da consulta.

Exemplo: a tabela tem somente 3 registros:

mes 01 | 35,00

mes 02 | 25,00

mes 03 | 98,00

A consulta deve me retornar esses 3 meses existente e completar o numero de registro com os 9 meses faltantes.

mes 01 | 35,00

mes 02 | 25,00

mes 03 | 98,00

- |
- |
- |
- |
- |
- |
- |
- |

Comment: Olá, você pode adicionar o código do que você já tentou?

Comment: não fiz nenhum código. isso tudo tem que ser feito somente em um select  no banco de dados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução passa por fazer a consulta a um conjunto de registos pré-definidos com os meses, juntando depois a tabela das rendas:

```
SELECT      M.Nome
        ,   SUM(IFNULL(Renda, 0)) AS Renda
FROM        (
                SELECT "Mes 01" AS Nome, 1 AS Mes
                UNION ALL
                SELECT "Mes 02" AS Nome, 2 AS Mes
                UNION ALL
                SELECT "Mes 03" AS Nome, 3 AS Mes
                UNION ALL
                SELECT "Mes 04" AS Nome, 4 AS Mes
                UNION ALL
                SELECT "Mes 05" AS Nome, 5 AS Mes
                UNION ALL
                SELECT "Mes 06" AS Nome, 6 AS Mes
                UNION ALL
                SELECT "Mes 07" AS Nome, 7 AS Mes
                UNION ALL
                SELECT "Mes 08" AS Nome, 8 AS Mes
                UNION ALL
                SELECT "Mes 09" AS Nome, 9 AS Mes
                UNION ALL
                SELECT "Mes 10" AS Nome, 10 AS Mes
                UNION ALL
                SELECT "Mes 11" AS Nome, 11 AS Mes
                UNION ALL
                SELECT "Mes 12" AS Nome, 12 AS Mes
          ) M
LEFT JOIN   Rendas R ON R.Mes = M.Mes
GROUP BY    M.Nome
```

Pode ver um exemplo funcional no DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t7feMk8o95L83WjEq3w7EP/0

Comment: Legal, vou tentar isso e já dou um retorno

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `case when` no Select para isso.
Segue um exemplo de uso:

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN valor = 0 THEN "-"
   ELSE mes
END as mes,
   CASE WHEN valor = 0 THEN " "
   ELSE valor
END AS valor
FROM tabela;
```

Você está dizendo o seguinte: quando a coluna "valor" estiver zerada, o mês irá exibir um traço, e o valor será um espaço em branco.

Comment: nao. a tabela tem somente 3 registros. faltam 9 registros.
se eu fizer um select na tabela, esse select vai me retornar somente 3 registros.
mas preciso que me retorne 12 registros

Comment: um CASE WHEN não ira funcionar porque não existe esses 9 registros na tabela.

Comment: Se você estiver utilizando os dados para serem exibidos em outra linguagem (php, por exemplo), dentro do loop de consulta você pode completar as informações até dar 12 resultados. O que eu faria, se não fosse utilizar outra linguagem para receber os dados, seria preencher todos os 12 registros no banco com valores zerados para que esse meu Select possa ser utilizado.

Comment: entendi perfeitamente sua reposta, seria uma ótima solução. só que nesse meu caso não tenho como fazer nenhum insert